# How to use more one parameters in SQL template for JXLS

Tags: sql, jxls

I have a SQL as below in a template file with JXLS, there are two query variables in the SQL, but I don't know how to fill the parameters, appreciate for your help!

```
jx:each(items="jdbc.query('SELECT * FROM DATA_DIE where stock_type = ? and matnr <> ?', '["1","1000"]')" var="DIE" lastCell="G2")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just list all the parameters separated by commas e.g.

```
jx:each(items="jdbc.query('SELECT * FROM DATA_DIE where stock_type = ? and matnr <> ?', '1', '1000')" var="DIE" lastCell="G2")
```

You can also skip quotes around values 1 and 1000 if they are just number fields.